# Representations of $\pi_1M$ and Heegaard Splittings

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory

I am reading Floer's Instanton-Invariant paper, and am stuck on a sentence. To set the stage:

Consider a closed connected oriented 3-manifold $M$ and the nonabelian group $SU_2$. Denote the equivalence classes of representations $\mathcal{R}(M)=Hom(\pi_1M,SU_2)/\text{ad}(SU_2)$.

Now given a Heegaard splitting $M=M_+\cup_SM_-$, one can consider $\mathcal{R}(M)$ as the intersection of $\mathcal{R}(M_+)$ and $\mathcal{R}(M_-)$ in $\mathcal{R}(S)$. Indeed, Seifert van-Kampen's theorem gives $\pi_1(M)\cong\pi_1(M_+)\ast_{\pi_1(S)}\pi_1(M_-)$ and then the statement follows by the universal property of amalgamated free products.

**The resulting intersection number (ignoring the trivial representation) can be shown to be independent of the particular Heegaard splitting.**
[The "result" refers to the integer-valued Casson invariant, which assigns a sign to each intersection $a\in\mathcal{R}$].

How is this done?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the resulting intersection."

Comment: Presumably what they're getting at is that $\mathcal R(M)$ is an idea that is independent of any particular presentation of $\pi_1 M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For completeness)

This is explained/proved in the main reference of the invariant: *Casson's Invariant for Oriented Homology 3-Spheres* (by Akbulut and McCarthy).